# Text file list as keys to lookup in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: input a text file list of items that correspond to keys within a defined dictionary, have the program print all values for all keys within that list. As you can see, the dictionary is set up to contain multiple values for each key. The dictionary reports values for individual keys just fine, but I'm having problems trying to get it to report values for multiple keys (defined within the text file list).

Here's the code:

```
# open the text file containing a list that will be looked up in the dictionary below 
with open('/home/matt/Source/python/fpkm-batch-lookup/lookuplist.txt', 'r') as lookupfile:
    lookup = str(lookupfile.read().splitlines())

# define output file
output = open('/home/matt/Source/python/fpkm-batch-lookup/output.csv', 'w')

# assign keydict dictionary keys and values as columns in input file
keydict = {}
data = open('/home/matt/Source/python/fpkm-lookup/input.csv', 'r')
for line in data:
    items = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    key, values = items[0], items[1:]
    keydict[key] = values

# write out key and values to output file
output.write(lookup + '\n' + str(keydict['Alt Name']) + '\n' + str(keydict[lookup]) + '\n')
```

Trying to run it, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/Source/python/fpkm-batch-lookup/run.py", line 17, in <module>
    output.write(lookup + '\n' + str(keydict['Alt Name']) + '\n' + str(keydict[lookup]) + '\n')
KeyError: "['ENSG00000196476_C20orf96', 'ENSG00000247315_ZCCHC3', 'ENSG00000225377_RP5-1103G7.4', 'ENSG00000177732_SOX12', 'ENSG00000101255_TRIB3']"
```

The listed items in the KeyError message are the items in the lookuplist text file. Is my code treating the entire lookuplist file as a key for looking up? How could I have it treat each line within this file as a key to look up instead?

Thanks!

Edit/Update:

The rather inelegant approach of using [0], [1], etc to designate each key to lookup and then write to the output file. Here's the final code I used:

```
# open the text file containing a list that will be looked up in the dictionary below 
lookuplist = open('/home/matt/Source/python/fpkm-batch-lookup/lookuplist.txt').read().splitlines()

# define output file
output = open('/home/matt/Source/python/fpkm-batch-lookup/output.csv', 'w')

# assign keydict dictionary keys and values as columns in input file
keydict = {}
data = open('/home/matt/Source/python/fpkm-lookup/input.csv', 'r')
for line in data:
    items = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    key, values = items[0], items[1:]
    keydict[key] = values

# write out key and values to output file - add more if needed

output.write(str(lookuplist[0]) + '\n' + str(keydict['Alt Name']) + '\n' + str(keydict[lookuplist[0]]) + '\n' + '\n')

output.write(str(lookuplist[1]) + '\n' + str(keydict['Alt Name']) + '\n' + str(keydict[lookuplist[1]]) + '\n' + '\n')

output.write(str(lookuplist[2]) + '\n' + str(keydict['Alt Name']) + '\n' + str(keydict[lookuplist[2]]) + '\n' + '\n')

# .... to the nth string number to lookup
```

Figured I'd update, for anyone else looking to do the same sort of thing.

Comment: First observation, your content being read from a file is going to be a string so you do not have to stringify it str(lookupfile.read().splitlines())

Comment: That looks to be your problem at a quick glance as I see "['ENSG00000196476_C20orf96',  Notice the double quote

Comment: Removing the str() from lookup = returns a TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list ... so that's why I threw the str() in.

Comment: What line number is it referencing

Comment: I am pretty sure that is because you are not referencing the items in lookup one at a time, look at my code below

Comment: Why not use a better structured file format?  Json comes to mind.  That removes all the parsing logic usually required with file input.  The only real problem here, as others have said, is that you end up with a list of keys which you cast to a strong rather than leaving as an enumerable list.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you change

```
with open('/home/matt/Source/python/fpkm-batch-lookup/lookuplist.txt', 'r') as lookupfile:
    lookup = str(lookupfile.read().splitlines())
```

to

```
with open('/home/matt/Source/python/fpkm-batch-lookup/lookuplist.txt', 'r') as lookupfile:
    lookup = lookupfile.read().splitlines()
```

You should be closer

However, I think you are going to want to lookup the items from the lookup list one at a time as lookup is a list

looking at your code again I have made some more changes though
I am not totally sure what you are doing but something like

```
for key in lookup:
    if key in keydict:
         output.write(key + '\n' + ','.join(keydict[key]) + '\n' +key +'\n')
```

I am really feeling my way here but this is as close as I can get to your output based on what you have in your question.  I can't find a reference to 'Alt Name' and your code gives no indication of how to access that key in the dictionary so I assume it is the value from the file read in originally.

Comment: Removing the str() from lookup = returns a TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: Right but notice my for key in lookup loop - is lookup supposed to be one key?

Comment: You are going to have another problem because there is no 'Alt Name' in the dictionary based on what I am seeing

Comment: I agree you should take a closer look at this answer. Once you split lines you have a list of keys, one per line. You certainly don't want to concatenate the items together.